# TYPO3: Hiding folders in ext:DAM, even for BE admin

Tags: git, typo3, dam

I have a TYPO3 installation with DAM, where some folders/files are managed by git repository (ie. `fileadmin/templates/*`), therefore I'd like to disable access to them from DAM and/or File module even for full backend admin to avoid conflicts in files changed through the backend. Of course I can't change the folder's permissions as they contains also public assets.

What is the correct way, to hide or disable writes from backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the general access problem with fileadmin/, i manage all my templates in typo3conf/. There i create a directory "templates" for example and manage my templates there.

In TYPO3 < 6.0 you have to set `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['addAllowedPaths'] = 'typo3conf/templates/';` to properly use your templates.

This also has the advantage that you basically only have to manage typo3conf/ in Git :)

Comment: Yeap, I thought about this, but had no idea, how to 'bit' it,  I'll check it asap, and let you know.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this exists only for files (`fileDenyPatter`).

You could implement an own storage with TYPO3 6+, which would be relatively easy.

But the fact that you are using DAM proves that you are still on 4.x. You will either need to find a hook or xClass the folder tree class.

Comment: Indeed, hiding auto created File Storage and replacing it with custom one (ie. only for `fileadmin/user_uploads`) did the trick in 6.0 :), could you advice me what is best approach for working with file's metadata? Ofc. if is there any doc describing changes in 6.0 in this topic it will be fine :)